# Layouting using Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I need to put a div beside two components.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container" autosize>
  <mat-drawer #drawer class="example-sidenav" mode="side">
    <p>Auto-resizing sidenav</p>
    <p *ngIf="showFiller">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
    <button (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" mat-raised-button>
      Toggle extra text
    </button>
  </mat-drawer>

  <mat-card>
    <div class="example-sidenav-content">
      <div class="col">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <h3 class="display-5" style="padding-left: 10px;">Main Window</h3>
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-6"><app-main-window></app-main-window></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">This should be beside the two components</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

What can I try next to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the two `div`s in a div with `class` `row`. Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <app-main-window></app-main-window>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    This should be beside the two components
  </div>
</div>
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbn4ny?file=app/sidenav-open-close-example.html) for your ref.

**Note:** Make sure to see it in a medium sized screen as you've used `col-md-6`